# How to update app badge when app is terminated in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, notifications, badge

I am using firebase to send and receive messages and also receive notifications. I can easily update badge when the app is running. However as soon as I close the app. App badge won't be updated if I receive a notification. The solutions I have tried are as following:

Putting `FlutterAppBadger` in `didChangeAppLifecycleState`.

Putting `FlutterAppBadger` in `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage`.

I couldn't find any answer nor someone who has the same problem. Any help will kindly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the admin SDK sendToDevice you are using to send?
If so, I have solved the problem by including badge not only in the data, but also in the notifications of the payload.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).